# I am taking a 6 day off for some personal chores. Is the sentence right?

Tags: sentence-construction

While speaking to a lady from HR dept. I told her:

> I am taking a 6 day off for some personal chores.

Is the sentence construction grammatically correct and does it sound natural?

Comment: I am taking six days off, or a six-day break.

Comment: It is neither, because you are using *day* instead of *days* and you use the phrase *personal chores*.